# Show that the orthocenter of $ABC$ lies on $P'Q'$, where $P',Q',R'$ are the symmetric points of $M$ to this sides of the triangle,$M$ on circumscribed

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let $M$ be a point on the circumscribed circle of the triangle $ABC$, $P,Q,R$ being the projections of $M$ on the sides of the triangle and $P',Q',R'$ the symmetric points of $M$ to this sides of the triangle. Show that the orthocenter of $ABC$ lies on $P'Q'$"

This kind of problem just kept me up at night, I searched a variety of articles on excircles and incircles, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incenter, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle, I could not find a solution to this.

Comment: Just use this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simson_line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page of Simson Line does not contain this, So I just give a proof (sketch) here...

[image]

WLOG $P'$ and $Q'$ are the symmetric points of $M$ w.r.t. $AB$, $BC$. Let $D$ be the intersection of the circle and the perpendicular line from $A$ to $BC$. So $H$ and $D$ are symmetric with respect to $BC$ (you could prove it yourself). Let $S$ be the symmetric point of $P'$ w.r.t. $BC$. So, to prove $P',Q',H$ are collinear, we need to prove $M,D,S$ are collinear.

We have $\angle CBD=\angle CAD=90^\circ-\angle ACB$, so $\angle AMD=\angle ABD=\angle ABC+90^\circ-\angle ACB$. Also, $\angle AMB=\angle ACB$, and since we have $MB=P'B=SB$, $\angle MBS=\angle CBS-\angle CBM=\angle CBP-\angle CBM = \angle ABC+\angle ABP-\angle CBM=\angle ABC+\angle ABM-\angle CBM=2\angle ABC$. So, we have $\angle BMS=90^\circ-\angle ABC$. Therefore, $\angle DMS=\angle DMA+\angle AMB+\angle BMS=\angle ABC+90^\circ-\angle ACB+\angle ACB+90^\circ-\angle ABC=190^\circ$. So $D,M,S$ are collinear.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose P'Q' intersect altitude BB' on a point lie K. Draw a circle on side AC as it's diameter, it intersect BB' at point F. Connect C to K and extend it to meet  circle on AC at point L. Extend altitude BB' to meet this circle at point D. Draw a line from L parallel with BD to meet side AC at point E.In triangle B'KC we have:

$\angle B'KC=\frac{\overset{\large\frown}{LF}+\overset{\large\frown}{CD}}2$

In triangle LAC we have:

$\angle LAC=\frac{\overset{\large\frown}{LC}}2$

But:

$\overset{\large\frown}{FC}=\overset{\large\frown}{CD}$

Therefore:

$\angle B'KC=\angle LAC \Rightarrow \triangle B'KC \sim \triangle ALC$

That means $\angle ALC=90^o$.The extension of AL meets altitude BB' at B because triangles ALE and
ABB' are similar. That means CL is an altitude from C on side AB. In this way K is coincident with orthocenter H.